# Selecting multiple rows from database [php]

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm currently only able to get output from on database, with the highest ID value.

To give you a better perspective, I'm having trouble getting the 3 ID's with the highest auto-increment. So, if I have data inputted into my database 10 times, there will be 10 rows with 10 id's, from 1-10.

I want to take and display only the ID's with 7-10 (3 highest ID's) onto an HTML canvas (I know how to do that with just one row) but I'm confused on how I can array 3 rows and how I go about doing that. Here's the current code I'm using for the one row:

```
 mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $con);

        $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY gid DESC LIMIT 1",
                             mysql_real_escape_string($h_team),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($a_team),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($g_date),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($g_time),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($g_place),
                             mysql_real_escape_string($gid));

        $result = mysql_query($query);

                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $home = $row['h_team'];
                    $away = $row['a_team'];
                    $date = $row['g_date'];
                    $time = $row['g_time'];
                    $place = $row['g_place'];
                    $id = $row['gid'];
                }
```

I'm using the "LIMIT 1" to only display the highest ID until I can figure out how to get the three highest, and display them out.

Any help or ideas is greatly appricated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `limit 3` then:

```
select *
from games
order by gid desc
limit 3
```

And then:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $home[] = $row['h_team'];
   $away[] = $row['a_team'];
   $date[] = $row['g_date'];
   $time[] = $row['g_time'];
   $place[] = $row['g_place'];
   $id[] = $row['gid'];
}
```

Comment: Let me test this. Give me a second.

Comment: Okay, I'm having trouble using the code you gave me. Should I array like this?:

$home['array1', 'array2', 'array3'] = $row['h_team'];

Comment: Nevermind! Worked perfectly. Thanks, such a simple solution.